# Linq group by and sum the values add another column to sum

Tags: c#, linq

We need one requirement of Linq with group by with multiple columns and add new column, based group by add the sum there...

Table here.

```
Section SecCode Name      Count(new column based on Section count)
ABC        A-1   Ram        3
ABC        A-1   Rashid     3
ABC        A-1   Mani       3
CCC        B-1   Kutty      2
CCC        B-1   Bala       2 
GGG        C-1   Ravi       1
```

WE have Datatable like above(3 columns), we need to group by & count the Section

also add to another column as "Count".

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: Have you got something that even partially works?

Comment: The two tables that you display are the same? Are these the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: Maybe this could help and show you a better way of asking LINQ questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853221/linq-grouping-data-twice

Comment: Any examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Yes both are same table only.
based on the Section values have to count and add new column...as shown in the thable

Comment: I have tried few but, unable to add new column as Count...

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
values.Select(v => new
{
  Section = v.Section,
  SecCode = v.SecCode,
  Name = v.Name,
  Count = values.Count(i => i.Section.Equals(v.Section))
});
```

Alternative (performance optimization for large tables):

```
var map = values.GroupBy(v => v.Section, v => v.Name)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var result = values.Select(v => new
    {
      Section = v.Section,
      SecCode = v.SecCode,
      Name = v.Name,
      Count = map[v.Section]
    });
```